# How to get the filename of a sample from a DataLoader?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torchvision

I need to write a file with the result of the data test of a Convolutional Neural Network that I trained. The data include speech data collection. The file format needs to be "file name, prediction", but I am having a hard time to extract the file name. I load the data like this:

```py
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

TEST_DATA_PATH = ...

trans = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
])

test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    root=TEST_DATA_PATH,
    train=False,
    transform=trans,
    download=True
)

test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
```

and I am trying to write to the file as follows:

```
f = open("test_y", "w")
with torch.no_grad():
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(test_loader, 0):
        outputs = model(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        file = os.listdir(TEST_DATA_PATH + "/all")[i]
        format = file + ", " + str(predicted.item()) + '\n'
        f.write(format)
f.close()
```

The problem with `os.listdir(TESTH_DATA_PATH + "/all")[i]` is that it is not synchronized with the loaded files order of `test_loader`. What can I do?

Answer (score 11):

Well, it depends on how your `Dataset` is implemented. For instance, in the `torchvision.datasets.MNIST(...)` case, you cannot retrieve the filename simply because there is no such thing as the filename of a single sample (MNIST samples are [loaded in a different way](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L79-L99)).

As you did not show your `Dataset` implementation, I'll tell you how this could be done with the `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(...)` (or any [`torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder(...)`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/ec203153095ad3d2e79fbf2865d80fe6076618fa/torchvision/datasets/folder.py#L57-L147)):

```py
f = open("test_y", "w")
with torch.no_grad():
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(test_loader, 0):
        outputs = model(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        sample_fname, _ = test_loader.dataset.samples[i]
        f.write("{}, {}\n".format(sample_fname, predicted.item()))
f.close()
```

You can see that the path of the file is retrieved during the [`__getitem__(self, index)`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/ec203153095ad3d2e79fbf2865d80fe6076618fa/torchvision/datasets/folder.py#L129), especifically [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/ec203153095ad3d2e79fbf2865d80fe6076618fa/torchvision/datasets/folder.py#L137).

If you implemented your own `Dataset` (and perhaps would like to support `shuffle` and `batch_size > 1`), then I would return the `sample_fname` on the `__getitem__(...)` call and do something like this:

```py
for i, (images, labels, sample_fname) in enumerate(test_loader, 0):
    # [...]
```

This way you wouldn't need to care about `shuffle`. And if the `batch_size` is greater than 1, you would need to change the content of the loop for something more generic, e.g.:

```py
f = open("test_y", "w")
for i, (images, labels, samples_fname) in enumerate(test_loader, 0):
    outputs = model(images)
    pred = torch.max(outputs, 1)[1]
    f.write("\n".join([
        ", ".join(x)
        for x in zip(map(str, pred.cpu().tolist()), samples_fname)
    ]) + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: thanks for the hint! i can read filename list from datasets.ImageFolder.samples[i][0]

Comment: I used your code but i am challenged to get filename for all of my images. could you please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71430015/accessing-the-filename-as-well-as-prediction-for-each-of-images-inside-the-test ? thanks a lot

Comment: @MonaJalal this first solution only works if your situattion is the same as the OP: `batch_size=1, shuffle=False`. Otherwise, you have to wrap your dataset with a custom one, as I suggested in the answer, returning `sample_fname` in your `__getitem__(...)`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, even if batch_size=1, on ImageFolder. I get the error `AttributeError: 'Subset' object has no attribute 'samples'` on the line `sample_fname, _ = test_loader.dataset.samples[i]`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @FerdinandoRandisi based on the error, your dataset is not a `DatasetFolder`, but a `Subset`. In this case, you need to access an extra `.dataset` attribute, and use to correct index based on your `Subset` indices.

Answer (score 1):

In general case [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataloader.html) is there to provide you the batches from the Dataset(s) it has inside.

AS @Barriel mentioned in case of single/multi-label classification problems, the `DataLoader` doesn't have image file name, just the tensors representing the images , and the classes / labels.

However, `DataLoader` constructor when loading objects can take small things (together with the Dataset you may pack the targets/labels and the file names if you like) , even a dataframe

This way, the `DataLoader` may somehow grab that what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you using PyCharm or any IDE that has debug tool, let use it to take a look inside your data_loader, hope you can see a list of filenames, like my case.

In my case,
My data_loader was created by mmsegmentation.
[image: Data_loader created by mmsegmentation]