# How to save image paths using PyTorch CNN

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have been working with a CNN in PyTorch and I need to save the image path and its associated predicted probabilities for each class (in this case the classes are pass or fail). This is my code to save the preds to a data frame:

```
preds_df = pd.DataFrame()   
class_labels = []


model_ft.eval()
for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(dataloaders['train']):
    inputs = inputs.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)
    class_labels.append(labels.tolist())
    output = model_ft(inputs)

    sm = torch.nn.Softmax()
    probabilities = sm(output) 
    arr = probabilities.data.cpu().numpy()
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr)

    preds_df = preds_df.append(df)


preds_df['prediction'] = preds_df.idxmax(axis=1)
class_list = [item for sublist in class_labels for item in sublist]
preds_df['label'] = class_list
preds_df.columns = ['pass (0)', 'fail (1)', 'prediction', 'label']


preds_df.to_csv('./zoom17CNN_preds.csv')
```

How can I save the image path as well for each file in the data loader? Thank you!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56699383/7615877) and [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloader-filenames-in-each-batch/4212). Basically, you have to manually write your `Dataset` such that it returns the filenames explicitly along with your images and labels.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @akshayk07! I ended up iterating over my image directories and saving the current image name and preds that way:

```
directory = "./get_preds/fail"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    school_id = filename[0:6]
    ids.append(school_id)
    to_open = "./get_preds/fail/" + filename
    png = Image.open(to_open)

    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),         
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

    img_t = transform(png)
    batch_t = torch.unsqueeze(img_t, 0)
    model_ft.eval()
    out = model_ft(batch_t)

    _, index = torch.max(out, 1)
    percentage = torch.nn.functional.softmax(out, dim=1)[0]
    class0.append(percentage[0].tolist())
    class1.append(percentage[1].tolist())

df['school_id'] = ids
df['pass (0)'] = class0
df['fail (1)'] = class1
df['label'] = 1
```